# RegEx epression to hilite sub name

Tags: regex

I am modifying a syntax file for a code editor that is using QT5
I have this expression in the RegEx rule definition...

```
[A-Za-z0-9_]+:
```

to syntax hilite subroutine names in a code editor window, it is working somewhat but not quite (see image below for detail).
I need some help to get it working right

Example code window multiline string: (ignore StackOverflow code hiliting)

```
Only the following 5 lines should hilite
mainSub:
mainSub:
main_Sub:      
main_Sub2:
  main_Sub2:  F

Following  lines should NOT hilite
F  main_Sub2:
main:Sub2
    CS = 0: Wait 20 us
    FDC=56:GF=9:
    Data1 = ID_WR: Gosub HT1621_ID
    Data1 = 0     : Gosub HT1621_Addr

Underscore is the only non alphanumeric chr allowed in the sub name
Space & Tab are allowed before & after
Semicolon must be the last character of the sub name.
```

Underscore is the only special chr allowed in the sub name.
Space & Tab are allowed before & after the sub name.
Semicolon must be the last character of the sub name.
Whitespace not allowed in sub name.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps like this? `^[^\S\r\n]*[A-Za-z0-9_]+:(?!\S).*` https://regex101.com/r/cREGbu/1

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful for me to analyze in regex101.

Comment: Did it work out?

Comment: Looks like QTgui engine has differences to the online RegEx sim.     I have simplified the expression now, it doesn't align fully to the rules I specified but it is acceptable.  ^[A-Za-z_]\w+:

Comment: Then maybe the lookahead `(?!\S)` is not supported. Perhaps `^[A-Za-z_]\w+:[^\r\n\S]*$` will also do https://regex101.com/r/TlthJx/1

Comment: In my editor I only get this line highlited  main:Sub2           I am happy with ^[A-Za-z_]\w+:   sub name has to be at the start of line but that's acceptable as simple is good. cheers